# How to model and compute the structure of high entropy alloys (HEAs) using SSOS methods with ATAT

Tags: density-functional-theory, crystallography, materials-design, special-quasirandom-structures, alloy-theoretic-automated-toolkit

I've recently been working on structural modeling of HEAs and got a little confused when I read about the SSOS approach. I would appreciate it if anyone is familiar with the SSOS method or MCSQS and can answer this question.

What is the Pair coorrelation function mentioned in the article and
how does he do his calculations.

The relevant literature on the SSOS method is as follows

1. 10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.105501 Efficient Ab initio Modeling of Random Multicomponent Alloys
2. 10.1103/PhysRevB.102.174209 Generalized small set of ordered structures method for the solid-solution phase of high-entropy alloys
3. 10.1016/j.commatsci.2020.110213 High-throughput calculations based on the small set of ordered structures method for non-equimolar high entropy alloys
4. 10.1016/j.jallcom.2021.160776 First-principles-based high-throughput computation for high entropy alloys with short range order
5. 10.1038/s41598-022-16082-w A first‑principles‑based high fidelity, high throughput approach for the design of high entropy alloys

Comment: +1 and welcome but MMSE has a policy of [one question per post](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/421/one-question-per-post-please). The three questions you asked seem perfectly valid questions to me to be asked in three separate posts.